# for() loop breaks when using the OR operator (C)

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

As a beginner, I have been typing away when I noticed OR (in C ||) broke the for loop. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    char ch;
    
    printf("Typing program...\n");
    printf("Type away:");
    for(;;) {
        
        ch = getchar();
        if(ch == '~' || '`') {
            
            break;
            
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

When compiled the code doesn't seem to return any errors, but the for loop breaks when I paste the right side of the OR operator. What could cause this? Code is from C for Dummies, while I was doing an "exercise". Everything that I tried else would result in an error.

Comment: *"When compiled the code doesn't seem to return any errors,"* You can fix that by compiling with `-Wall   -Wextra -Werror` when using gcc or clang. Compile with `-W4 -WX` when using the microsoft compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [logical OR operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Logical_operators) needs a condition on both sides, therefore the condition in the if-statement has to be the following:

```
if (ch == '~' || ch == '`') {
    break;
}
```

Otherwise `` '`' `` will be treated as a condition by itself, which will always be true, because the value of the character `` '`' `` is not equal to `0`.